# Using serviceKey as constructor parameter for class resolved by DryIoc

Tags: ioc-container, dryioc

I'm registering two dependant classes with service keys.

```
container.Register<IPmgrProvisioning, PmgrProvisioningFrontEnd>(Reuse.Singleton, serviceKey: TelephonySystem.ALE);
container.Register<IPmgrUserProcessor, PmgrUserProcessor>(made: Parameters.Of.Type<IPmgrProvisioning>(serviceKey: TelephonySystem.ALE), serviceKey: TelephonySystem.ALE);
pmgrHandler = container.Resolve<IPmgrProvisioning>(serviceKey: TelephonySystem.ALE) as PmgrProvisioningFrontEnd;
```

So, the constructor of PMGRUserProcessor gets the proper IPmgrProvisioning implementation at resolve time. PmgrUserProcessor has this constructor

```
public PmgrUserProcessor(IAudmService iService, IPmgrProvisioning iPmgrProvisioning)
```

What I'd like to do is have another parameter in that constructor, so, something like

```
public PmgrUserProcessor(IAudmService iService, IPmgrProvisioning iPmgrProvisioning, object serviceKey = null)
```

And I'd like the parameter serviceKey to be TelephonySystem.ALE in my resolve. And If I were to resolve without a serviceKey, the serviceKey parameter in the PmgrUserProcessor would not be provided and thus remain empty.

Any idea on how to get this done?

Comment: What do you want to resolve without key, IPmgrUserProcessor? But in the example it is also registered with key.

Answer (score -1):

You may try: `Parameters.Of.Type(...).Name("serviceKey", req => req.ServiceKey)`. 
Check the Name and Type overloads for the other options.